LED Breather circuit with only analog components running on 1.2 V?
A friend of mine wants to modify a cheap solar lamp to make it breath (fade in and out continously). The LED runs on a 1.2 V NiMH battery. I'd like to design a circuit which could go in series with the LED and make it breath in and out at 1 second interval. Is this possible? Some sort of ramping vibrator circuit?

There must be some simple voltage conversion circuit inside the lamp, because a LED for visible light needs more than 1.2 V to operate. A solution must cooperate with this circuit, so it must be known.

no, the "boost" converter in the lamp requires a fairly constant load. you might be able to use a "slow flash" LED, but trying to power a secondary controller will yield poor results.

I can assure you this led is running on 1.2v.  There is no boost converter.  The circuit board has connectors for a solar cell, the led lamp, one transistor and one resistor.

@tavis And I can assure you it is not running on 1.2 V, because an LED at 1.2 V emits only infrared. The "transistor" may be a highly-integrated boost converter, and the "resistor" its associated inductor? Either that or you're missing something, because visible-light LEDs physically cannot operate at voltages below about 1.5 V, and then you'll only get deep red.

I put a scope on it and the led itself is getting a 2.5v square-ish wave. So that thing I thought was a transistor is actually a 4 pin chip and it must be doing a boost or joule thief kinda thing.
